# USB keyboard not writing an additional language on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: usb, keyboard, input-language

I am attaching an external Microsoft USB keyboard to my laptop which runs Ubuntu 20.04. Although I have 2 input languages installed, English and Hebrew, only the English input works. When I switch to Hebrew, it still produces English characters (the built-in laptop keyboard works OK).
How can I fix it?

Comment: FYI:  Ubuntu has both *yy* releases (eg. Ubuntu Core 20) and *yy.mm* releases (eg. Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server/Desktop), and they are different products. Your title does not match your description (instead implies a different product was installed).

Comment: I see that you found a workaround. However, it would be valuable if you could help test a proposed fix of [bug #1899206](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1899206). If so, please upgrade the mutter packages from [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~gunnarhj/+archive/ubuntu/mutter) and let us know if it makes a difference (i.e. without the workaround you figured out).

Comment: Hello, Gunnar. I had the same problem, and changing the input sources was only a temporary solution. I updated mutter from your PPA and it fixed the problem. My USB keyboard now uses the correct language. It also fixed a problem where application hot keys still used the qwerty keys (for example, I still had to press the ctrl + old t to open a new tab in chrome).

Answer (score 3):

In case it helps anyone else, I managed to solve it (trial and error...)
In the settings of input sources, I dragged Hebrew to be above English, and then the Hebrew input started working on the external USB keyboard.

Comment: thank you so much! I was going crazy. I have the same issue and now it's solved thanks to you.

Comment: weird. But it worked. Thanks.